# Include Active Storage attachments in Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activestorage

Using Rails 5.2 and Active Storage, I set up an `Item` class with some `images`:

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

I'd like to use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.includes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) to eager-load the `images`, pretty standard Rails stuff with `has_many`, but:

```rb
Item.includes(:images)
=> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError ("Association named 'images' was not found on Item; perhaps you misspelled it?")

Item.includes(:attachments)
=> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError ("Association named 'attachments' was not found on Item; perhaps you misspelled it?")

Item.includes(:active_storage_attachments)
=> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError ("Association named 'active_storage_attachments' was not found on Item; perhaps you misspelled it?")
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 17):

ActiveStorage provides a method to prevent N+1 queries

```
Gallery.where(user: Current.user).with_attached_photos
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html#method-i-has_many_attached

So, in your case:

```
Item.with_attached_images
```

Comment: That worked. But the link you provided is not working
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Macros.html

Answer (score 9):

…aaand I found the answer:

```rb
Item.reflections.keys
=> ["location", "images_attachments", "images_blobs", "taggings", "base_tags", "tag_taggings", "tags"]
```

The name of the Active Storage-generated association is `images_attachments` even though it is accessible through `Item#images`. Here's the solution:

```rb
Item.includes(:images_attachments)
  Item Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" IN ($3, $4, $5, $6, $7)  [["record_type", "Item"], ["name", "images"], ["record_id", 3], ["record_id", 2], ["record_id", 4], ["record_id", 5], ["record_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation […]>
```